# PHP GET Variable containing forward slashes rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to achieve the following:

Rewrite:

```
http://url.com?subfolder=folderone/foldertwo/folderthree
```

To:

```
http://url.com/subfolder/folderone/foldertwo/folderthree
```

And call `$_GET['subfolder']` within PHP, which should retrieve `folderone/foldertwo/folderthree`

This works as expected when defining `?subfolder=` but not with the following as it tries to find a folder with that path:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subfolder/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?subfolder=$1 [L]
```

Is the above possible?

Thanks!

Comment: In the first URL the part "folderone/foldertwo/folderthree" is _not_ considered the value of the argument "subfolder", since that would violate the encoding. Is that an URL you create yourself? Then you should fix it instead of trying to work around the issue introduced earlier.

Comment: It will just a URL that will be navigated to, but still stay on `index.php` itself. Im trying to have it as a template to navigate to the subfolder of a user's main folder. Kind of like Dropbox, where when you click say on a folder named 'Images' it will navigate to `https://www.dropbox.com/home/images` and enter that folder. When you navigate within subfolders of 'images', the folder names will just append to the URL.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: That was not an answer to my question. I will try it the other way round: you have to encode that path to use it inside a url get parameter. Take a look at the `urlencode()`: http://php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Oh if you mean if the URL may be created dynamically, then yes, it will be a link in an anchor href. I tried   `<?php $query_string = 'subfolder=' . urlencode('new/next/now');
                echo '<a href="?' . htmlentities($query_string) . '">go</a>'; 
                echo $_GET['subfolder'];
                ?> ` , works fine and everything until I remove `?subfolder=` so that the URL is rewritten, but then it looks for `/new/next/now` again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*)$ index.php?subfolder=$1 [L]
```